# how to access in view pushed object into empty array

Tags: angularjs

how to access pushed array in view part

```
          $scope.addCart = function(){
           $scope.viewDetails=[];
           $scope.viewDetails.push({"name":"mobile"});
           $scope.viewDetails.push({"price":"23"});
           $scope.viewDetails.push({"location":"hyd"});
            }
```

Comment: Doesn't make sense pushing objects with different properties into array. Why aren't all those combined as one object?

Answer (score 0):

hi if u use an array the angular library behavior is two way data binding which means if u use the array in your html any whee it will automatiocally update the array values.

```
 <div ng-repeat="buffDoc in bufferDocs" class="font-BB"><span>{{buffDoc.name}}:</span>
                </div>
```

and in your controller

```
 $scope.bufferDocs=[{name:"hello"}];
```

so when the array have changes it automatically reflects in the html